# Table react bootstrap component rendering from array

Tags: javascript, jsx, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

I want to render a Table component with N rows, where N corresponds to a given array lenght, and for each row there will be two columns: the 1st one with a parameter of the array of objects and the 2nd with the other parameter. How can i do that?
Here's a backbone

```
<Table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>param #1</th>
                    <th>param #2</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                ...for array.length-times...(
                <td>array[0].param1</td>
                <td>array[0].param2</td>
                ....)
            </tbody>
        </Table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand your question, you can use a [map() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to do that. Here is the sample code.

```
<Table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>param #1</th>
      <th>param #2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {yourArray.map(arrayData=>{
    return(
    <tr>
      <td>arrayData.param1</td>
      <td>arrayData.param2</td>
    </tr>
    )
    }
    )}
  </tbody>
</Table>
```